# How to filter by property of a reference in Firebase's where()

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

## Background

I have two firebase collections, `dates` and `seats`, whose (simplified) schema looks like this:

```
dates: [
    { time: Timestamp }
]

seats: [
    { date: reference to a date }
]
```

Of course, there is more information on each collection, but the idea here is that multiple seats can link to the same date.

The task at hand is to fetch only seats with dates that lie in the future.

My first instinct was to use 'in':

```
const futureDates = await firestore.collection(DATES)
        .where('time', '>', new Date())
        .get()
const seats = await firestore.collection(SEATS)
        .where('date', 'in', futureDates.docs.map(date => date.ref))
        .get()
```

But then I could only use 10 dates at once:

> **Limitations**
>
> Note the following limitations for in and array-contains-any:
>
> in and array-contains-any support up to 10 comparison values.

(https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries)

## Question

Is it possible to do it more elegantly and access the `time` property of `date` directly in the search query of `seats`?

Something along the lines of:

```
const seats = await firestore.collection(SEATS)
    .where('date.time', '>', new Date()) // This always returns 0 seats though
    .get()
```

Comment: Firestore does not have the ability to effectively "join" two collections in a query.  Consider restructuring your data to support this query.  Duplicating data between collections is common in nosql type databases in order to support queries like this.

Comment: @DougStevenson Thanks, if you post it as an answer, I'll accept it :D

Comment: If you have an actual implementation that works, you could answer for yourself. That would probably be more useful to others going forward.